# How can I eliminate an odor in an unvented bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, smell

I have a very small bathroom in my office.  The said bathroom is unventilated.  Obviously it leads to a foul smell in the bathroom.  Please suggest to me some method by which the foul smell can be eliminated.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install a fan vented to the outside
2. Install a fan with a carbon filter that recirculates air
3. Spray a deordorizer/fragrance
4. Put a clothes-pin over your nose
5. Eat foods that result to less foul smelling bowel movements
6. Close the door and hope for the best

Comment: Lighting candles, striking a match, and/or installing air fresheners are also common solutions.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue but it's our home toilet. We found the best way to eliminate all odours is to use a plug-in purifier.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may want to consider pulling the toilet and replacing the wax ring. Make sure your flange is in good condition, level and at the proper height. My understanding is that a bad wax ring can leak sewer gas but still not leak water.